# Understanding git pull vs git pull origin vs git pull branch_name

Tags: git, bitbucket

Suppose I have checked out a developer branch {develop} from git. From this all developers create local individual branches , make changes and push. Now if I am checked out to my local branch created from remote develop branch , so what would be difference between these 3 commands:

1. git pull
2. git pull origin
3. git pull origin develop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+origin+master+difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 will merge changes from your local branch's upstream branch (IOW, the branch it is tracking). If it is a remote branch (not always the case, your upstream branch might be a local branch and I see lots of examples out there of workflows using *local* copies of shared branches, which I dim complete unnecessary... but alas), it will fetch from the remote before merging.

2 will fetch from remote `origin` and merge the upstream branch.

3 will fetch from `origin` and merge whatever is in branch `origin/develop`, regardless of it being your local branch's upstream or not.